# How to clear a multi-select choice field using SPD workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, multi-select

I have a field with type Choice (menu to choose from) which allows multiple selections (checkboxes).

At a certain point in my workflow I want to uncheck all the current item's checkboxes. Is this doable in SPD? I tried setting the field to an empty parameter, nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow answer should meet your requirement.

> I've done this by using an Initiation Form Parameter called nullString
>   of type Single Line of Text, and not setting the Default value. Then I
>   can set values and variables elsewhere equal to this parameter.

See [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/110425/21421)

Comment: I actually tried this before posting the question and it didn't work, so I thought it must be something special with multi-select fields. I tried it again and now it works! Must have missed something when I tried it the first time. Thank you!

Comment: that is okay! in future don't forget to mention what you have tried so far

Comment: I did mention it in the original post, but I guess I could have been more detailed. Here are the steps that I had followed: http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2010/01/22/how-to-set-a-column-to-null-with-spd-aspx/